# How can I zero-pad a hexadecimal digit string to eight digits?

Tags: java, hex

I have a logic requirement, where I need to ensure that a hexadecimal digit string is presented in 8-digit format, even if the leading digits are zero.  For example, the string corresponding to 0x3132 should be formatted as "0x00003132".

I tried this:

```
String key_ip = txt_key.getText(); 
int addhex = 0; 
char [] ch = key_ip.toCharArray (); 
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

for (char c : ch) { 
    int z = (int) c;
    builder.append(Integer.toHexString(z).toUpperCase()); 
} 
System.out.println("\ n (key) is:" + key_ip); 
System.out.println("\ nkey in Hex:" + addhex + builder.toString());
```

, but it gave me an error.  Can anyone explain how to fix or rewrite my code for this?

and I want to ask one more thing, if use code

```
Long.toHexString(blabla);
```

is it true to change the value "0x00" to "\0030" so that the output of 0 is 30

Comment: Did you try anything? Setting up a small test application and playing around with it while reading some of the Javadocs shouldn't be too hard. If you tried something yet please share your code.

Comment: Do you mean eight *hexadecimal digits*?  It requires a minimum of *fourteen* **bits** to represent the hexadecimal value `3132`.

Comment: Since this seems to be about formatting numbers as text, have you considered using a [`Formatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)?

Comment: As for the question about `Long.toHexString()`, I have no idea what you're actually trying to ask.  The proposition you present seems unlikely to be true on its face, but it also seems like something you should be able to test easily.

Comment: @DanielTampubolon, if you have code to present or any other substantial clarification then please [*edit it into the question*](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57008978/edit).  But I'll fix the bits / digits wording for you.

Comment: im so sorry @JohnBollinger

Comment: With respect to your example code, is `txt_key.getText()` itself providing a hexadecimal string, such as your "3132"?  If so, does it include a leading "0x"?  Your example would be improved (for the purposes of the question) by updating it to initialize `key_ip` with a representative String literal.

Comment: thank you @JohnBollinger I don't know how to edit my question, because this is the first time I've joined this discussion other than Kaskus, and I haven't mastered too many English conversations :)

Comment: @JohnBollinger in txt_key.getText () I enter the input number in the form of "12", then I change "12" into hexadecimal which is "3132" well I want to add 8 bits, so 00000012 is in decimal, what about hexadecimal? 00003132 or something like that

Comment: Well that puts your example code in a different light, but it also introduces an entirely separate and unnecessary complication around converting characters to corresponding Unicode values.  That conversion doesn't seem to be what the question is actually about.

Comment: that right  @JhonBollinger  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evidently, you are receiving a `String`, converting its `char`s to their Unicode code values, and forming a `String` containing the hexadecimal representations of those code values.  The problem you want to solve is to left-pad the result with `'0'` characters so that the total length is not less than eight.  In effect, the only parts of the example code that are directly related to the problem itself are

> ```
> int addhex = 0;
> ```

and

> ```
> System.out.println("\ nkey in Hex:" + addhex + builder.toString());
> ```

. Everything else is just setup.

It should be clear, however, that that particular attempt cannot work, because all other considerations aside, you need something that adapts to the un-padded length of the digit string. That computation has no dependency on the length of the digit string at all.

Since you're already accumulating the digit string in a `StringBuilder`, it seems sensible to apply the needed changes *to it*, before reading out the result.  There are several ways you could approach that, but a pretty simple one would be to just `insert()` zeroes one at a time until you reach the wanted length:

```
while (builder.length() < 8) {
    builder.insert(0, '0');  // Inserts char '0' at position 0
}
```

I do suspect, however, that **you may have interpreted the problem wrongly**.  The result you obtain from doing what you ask is ambiguous: in most cases where such padding is necessary, there are several input strings that could produce the same output.  I am therefore inclined to guess that what is actually wanted is to pad the digits corresponding to each input character **on a per-character basis**, so that an input of "12" would yield the result "00310032".  This would be motivated by the fact that Java `char` values are 16 bits wide, and it would produce a transformation that is reliably reversible.  If that's what you really want, then you should be able to adapt the approach I've presented to achieve it (though in that case there are easier ways).

---

> if use code
>
> ```
> Long.toHexString(blabla);
> ```
>
> is it true to change the value "0x00" to "\0030" so that the output of
>   0 is 30

The Unicode code value for the character '0', expressed in hexadecimal, is 30.  Your method of conversion would produce that for the input string `"0"`.  Your method does not lend any special significance to the character '\' in its input.

Comment: ty @John Bollinger i will try it :)

Comment: its works, ty @JohnBollinger, :) ty for solution

may I ask one more question jhon?

what if the hex digit is more than eight bits? does it use builder.delete ()? or there are other methods, :)

Comment: @DanielTampubolon, if you have an intermediate result longer than eight characters then `builder.delete()` is a viable option to remove the extras.  So is `builder.toString().substring()`.

Comment: thank you for the helpful information @JohnBollinger :)